# How-many-hedron is round enough?

Tags: geometry, statistics, euclidean-geometry

Let $X$ be a convex polytope that contains the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ (In $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$). If
$$\sup_{\textbf{a}\in \mathbb{S}^n}\sup_{\textbf{x}\in X}\textbf{a}.\textbf{x}\leq1+\varepsilon$$
then how many faces does $X$ AT LEAST have?

The condition simply says the polytope is never more than $\varepsilon$ apart from the sphere and is therefore fairly smooth and round. An asymptotic answer suffices.

PS: I came up with this problem out of curiosity, not sure if it has any applications.

Comment: Suppose they are packed fairly evenly, with an angle $2\theta$ between them.  There are roughly $O(\theta^{-n})$ of them, and each extends to a distance $\sec\theta$ from the centre.  I think thst gives $O(\epsilon^{-n/2})$ of them